# How many switches to reach all possible connections?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given $n$ points numbered $1, 2, \cdots, n$, provide some edges, such that for each partition of the $n$ points, we can choose some edges from the provided ones, so that any two points in $1, 2, \cdots, n$ are connected iff they are in the same set. It's fine if you use some more points, and we don't care what they're connected to.

E.g. Let $n=3$, and we can provide $(1,4), (2,4), (3,4)$. If any two, taking example 1 and 2, are in a same set, while the other is not, choose $(1,4)$ and $(2,4)$. Choose nothing if the three are separated, or all if they're in same set. Of course, $(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)$ is also valid.

As I know, when $n=5$, we can provide only 9 edges, $(1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (4,6), (5,6), (2,7), (3,7), (4,7), (5,7)$, one less than connecting every pair of points.

Now for large $n$, how many edges at least should be provided? I know it can be done in $\mathcal O(n \log^2 n)$, but not whether it's best result, neither what the constant is.

Comment: If you are asking what is the minimal size of $M$ to make the following expression true, the answer is $\Omega(n^2)$, and not $O(n\log^2(n))$   $$\forall n\in\mathbb N\quad \exists M\subset[n]\times[n]\quad\forall A,B\subset [n]\quad s.t\quad A\uplus B=[n] \quad\wedge\quad A=K_{\vert A\vert}\quad\wedge\quad B=K_{\vert B\vert}$$

Comment: @TheHolyJoker I don't quite understand you, but I mean smallest $M$ that, $$\forall f: \{1,2,\cdots,n\} \rightarrow \mathbb N, \exists S\subseteq M, \forall 1\le a<b\le n, \left(f(a)=f(b)\iff \exists k,p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_k, p_1=a\wedge p_k=b\wedge \forall 1\le i<k,\{p_i,p_{i+1}\}\in S \right)$$. Used function to mean equivment as I don't quite know how to express in standard